# Not enough space in /var/cache/apt/archives/

Tags: apt, package-management, disk-usage

When I run the command to install the package solr-jetty, I am told

```
You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

Here's the result of the `df -H` command:

[image]

I have installed Ubuntu with VirtualBox on my Mac.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: In my case, this problem went away by just rebooting the system. I guess my computer has commutated very much temporary files.

Answer (score 80):

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

This will delete all packages not currently installed. If that doesn't free up enough space, then use `sudo apt-get clean`. This clears out all `.debs` downloaded and/or installed.

But it looks like your hard disk is out of space. Seriously out of space. 61Mb is not enough for a good working system. I found 2 alternatives that can circumvent space-related problems though both might be hard to pull off when using a virtual machine.
A more permanent solution would be to increase the size of your virtual machine (and I would also advise using the method that allows the machine to dynamically increase in size; VirtualBox has such a setting).

---

> Alternative if you have a partition or external storage.

With this method you re-route the location where `.deb`s are stored:

```
sudo mv -i /var/cache/apt /media/{dir_of_mounted_disc}
sudo ln -s /media/{dir_of_mounted_disc}/apt /var/cache/apt
```

Run the upgrade and install. After you are done you can switch back to normal with:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo unlink /var/cache/apt
sudo mv /media/{dir_of_mounted_disc}/apt /var/cache
```

Of course {dir_of_mounted_disc} needs to be changed to the name of your mounted disc.

> Another alternative

This way you create a RAM disc:

```
sudo mkdir /media/{directory}
sudo mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /media/{directory}
sudo ln -s /media/{directory}/apt /var/cache/apt
```

Clean up as with the 1st alternative.

**Warning** this requires a large amount of RAM so may not be useable when using a virtual system.

Comment: I tried the two commands and I have the same 'not enough space' message

Comment: So I edited my question put the visual result of the command (soory I put some image because I don't know how to copy paste the content of the shell...)

Comment: By the way, I tried with what I got by doing ls in the media directory, I found 'cdrom'. So I ran the sudo mw command and I got an error message : could not create directory /media/cdrom/apt : 'read only filme system'...

Comment: Do you mean the last command you suggested are useless if I don't have a USB stick or an external HDD ?

Comment: @newben no problem :) if you do not mind please remove all the comments (except the 1st one :D ) since we are turning this in a chat :+

Comment: if you are creating a docker image, your linux host must have free disk space. When images creation fail, we get failed images consuming disk space in host. List the failed images with `docker images` and choose which one to remove with `docker rmi <image id>`

Answer (score 9):

Whenever you install a program, the packages (.deb files) get stored in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, which obviously take up space (a lot of space if there are many packages installed).

To get rid of them, use:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Incase you're wondering what is the difference between `clean` and `autoclean`, here is what the man page says:

**clean:**  clean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. It removes everything but the lock file from /var/cache/apt/archives/ and /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/. APT is used as a dselect(1) method, clean is run Those who do not use dselect will likely want to run apt-get clean time to time to free up disk space.

**autoclean**: Like clean, autoclean clears out the local repository of package files. The difference is that it only removes package files can no longer be downloaded, and are largely useless. This a cache to be maintained over a long period without it out of control. The configuration option Clean-Installed will prevent installed packages from erased if it is set to off.

Answer (score 9):

These commands will remove extra packages that are no longer required .

Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) and type

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 3):

this error message showed up on a raspberry pi zero-w with fresh install of Raspbian 10 Buster:

```
You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.
```

The other answers here are valid, but this fresh image had no significant previous packages for removal, so removing them didn't help.

solution (1): **use raspi-config --> Advanced --> Expand Filesystem**

this will [expand the root filesystem](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=39824) to use the entire sd card.

solution (2): or [from the command line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=195836):

```
raspi-config --expand-rootfs
```

Answer (score 3):

I hit this error and fixed this by removing none docker.
you can remove none docker by one of these lines:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q) -f
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker image rm $(docker image ls -f 'dangling=true' -q)
```

Comment: Does this answer address the question?

Comment: Yes, this is about freeing up space in ubuntu.

Comment: Yes I agree with @AliGanjbakhsh. I ran `docker system prune` to remove dangling containers & images, and it solved my out of space error.

Comment: If you're looking for this issue in the context of a docker container - this is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65291124/docker-you-dont-have-enough-free-space-in-var-cache-apt-archives

Comment: In general you should use `xargs` to pipe in arguments instead of command substitution.

Answer (score 2):

The issue re: 'You don't have enough free spacve in /var/cache/apt/archives/' may be related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1054903
Particularly if /var/cache/apt is on a tmpfs which gets erased every boot. Is it possible that you've sym-linked /var/cache/ to /tmp/cache/ or something similar in order to save space?

If this is the case the instructions to solve/work-arround it are on the bug report above.

Comment: Can you add a summary of the suggested workaround, quote parts that need quoting, and add relevant steps to take from the link.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a workaround/helpful tip.

This was happening on my virtual machine because I had allocated too much space to swap (close to 40%). I quickly resized it using `gparted` and was able to reclaim some more space for the root partition.

Now I can update the long neglected VM which required about 3GB of updates.

Comment: Docker images for me. Removed the ones I didn't need.