# Frozen Login due to lack of space on Lubuntu 23.04 - Acer Chromebook N15Q10

Tags: command-line, upgrade, lubuntu, login, chromebook

my issue started after I checked for and applied (I think) a full system upgrade.

The issue is that I am faced with a frozen login screen after I've correctly entered my password entered. The mouse can move, but clock is stuck and the text cursor not blinking.

The power button works.

When I reach login screen again, instead of typing in my password, I press

ctrl + alt + refresh

I reach a text terminal which reads:

```
Ubuntu 23.04 myname-gnawty tty3
myname-gnawty login:
```

I enter my name, then my password, and then I get an Ubuntu welcome message, which starts with

```
Welcome to Ububtu 23.0.4 (GNU/Linuc 6.2.0-26-generic x86_64)
```

There follows a list of links to websites for documentation, management, and support.

It also reads

```
0 updates can be applied immediately.
```

After some copyright and warranty info, the last line is

```
myname@myname-gnawty:~$
```

with a blinking cursor.

The output of `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop^` contains,

```
Suggested packages: hunspell openoffice.org-hunspell | openoffice.org-core
The following NEW packages will be installed: hunspell-en-us  0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1499 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 794 MB/901 MB of archives. After this operation 899 kB of additional disk space will be used.
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

How do I get to using Lubuntu on my Chromebook as usual again? What should I do next?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop^`, and reboot

Comment: I'm a little wary of just entering commands in when I'm not sure of the reasoning behind them, but I appreciate the comment @ArchismanPanigrahi - Could you elaborate on your reasoning for this? Thanks.

Comment: This command reinstalls the lubuntu desktop environment, just in case some important component went missing/corrupted during the upgrade. Also, I am glad you don't want to blindly enter any commands

Comment: Okay cool, thanks @ArchismanPanigrahi. Just to clarify, do I need to include the `^` character after `desktop`? Or is that a typo. Your suggestion is similar to a line suggested here (https://ubunlog.com/en/how-to-reinstall-in-graphical-environment-of-ubuntu-when-the-desktop-does-not-load/), but without the  `^` so I just wanted to double check.

Comment: I have seen people recommending `^` for metapackages like lubuntu-desktop, but I am not very sure what it exactly does. You can also try without the `^`, it should not alter the results much

Comment: Okay, I did it without the  `^`
Here's the last few lines of what I got.
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4540 B of archives.
After this operation 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/`
@ArchismanPanigrahi

Comment: I rebooted and tried your original suggestion, with the `^` after `desktop`, @Arc. A lot more lines, starting with `Note` and ending with
`Suggested packages:
hunspell openoffice.org-hunspell | openoffice.org-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
hunspell-en-us

0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1499 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 794 MB/901 MB of archives.
After this operation 899 kB of additional disk space will be used.
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/`

Rebooted again and am back at square one (initial question).

Comment: Hmm. Most likely, your Chromebook has ran out of space (which can easily happen for 32 GB system partition), and the last update could not be completed due to that. Try removing snapd (you can later replace snap packages with their APT counterparts - snap consumes a significant amount of space) `sudo apt purge --autoremove snapd`. Then, try reinstalling the desktop environment, and also perform a full upgrade with `sudo apt full-upgrade`, and reboot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not enough space in /var/cache/apt/archives/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178909/not-enough-space-in-var-cache-apt-archives)

Answer (score 0):

The error `E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/`  shows that your Chromebook ran out of space, and it cannot install updates anymore. Given you have only 32GB internal storage, this is possible if you install quite a few programs.

Let's clear some disc space.

Firstly, you can try replacing snap packages with their APT counterparts (which consume significantly less disc space).

To free up some disc space, run

```
sudo apt purge snapd
```

Remove unnecessary dependencies with

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Delete the apt cache with

```
sudo apt clean
```

Then, try reinstalling the desktop environment, and also perform a full upgrade with `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Afterwards, uninstall the apps you won't need.